# Why can delete operator be used in const context?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

This question is different from:

- [Is a destructor considered a const function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372456/is-a-destructor-considered-a-const-function)
- [new-expression and delete-expression on const reference and const pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327785/new-expression-and-delete-expression-on-const-reference-and-const-pointer)
- [Deleting a pointer to const (T const*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755196/deleting-a-pointer-to-const-t-const)

---

I wrote a class `Test` like this.

```
class Test {

    private:

        int *p;

    public:

        //constructor
        Test(int i) {
            p = new int(i);
        }

        Test & operator = (const Test &rhs) {
            delete p;
            p = new int(*(rhs.p));
            return *this;
        }

};
```

When the parameter `rhs` of the operator function is itself (i.e. `Test t(3); t = t;`), `delete p;` also changes the pointer `p` **of `rhs`**. Why is this allowed?

C++ standard (N3092, "*3.7.4.2 Deallocation functions*") says

> If the argument given to a deallocation function in the standard library is a pointer that is not the null pointer value (4.10), the deallocation function shall deallocate the storage referenced by the pointer, **rendering invalid all pointers** referring to any part of the deallocated storage. The effect of using an invalid pointer value (including passing it to a deallocation function) is undefined.

(Note: *delete-expression* internally calls a deallocation function. So this excerpt is related with `delete` operator.)

So I think `delete p;` may change the member `p` of `rhs` though `rhs` is a const reference.

Someone may insist that "to render a pointer invalid is **not** to change the value of a pointer" but I don't find such a statement in the standard. I doubt there is a possibility that the address pointed by `rhs`'s `p` has been changed after `delete p;` in `operator =`(*).

(*): Whether or not this situation can be reproduced on popular compilers doesn't matter. I want a theoretical guarantee.

---

Supplement:

I've changed `delete p;` to `delete rhs.p;`, but it still works. Why?

Full code here:

```
#include <iostream>

class Test {

    private:

        int *p;

        //print the address of a pointer
        void print_address() const {
            std::cout << "p: " << p << "\n";
        }

    public:

        //constructor
        Test(int i) {
            p = new int(i);
        }

        Test & operator = (const Test &rhs) {

            print_address(); //=> output1
            delete rhs.p;
            print_address(); //=> output2

            p = new int(*(rhs.p));
            return *this;

        }

};

int main() {

    Test t(3);
    t = t;

}
```

In this case, it is guaranteed that `p` is invalidated. But who guarantees `invalidate != (change the value)`? i.e. Does the standard guarantee that `output1` and `output2` are the same?

Comment: That's a side effect of your own change. But `const` doesn't mean that the object `rhs` will not change over time, it just means that you (accessing `rhs`) cannot change it.

Comment: There’s no ”also” — `*this` is the same object as `rhs`.

Comment: You have a `const` reference parameter, but not a `const` object. That means that you're not allowed to use that reference to change the object. It doesn't mean that the referred-to object is immutable.

Comment: `this` is not `const` and `this` is the object being operated on. The fact that `rhs`  is the same as `*this` is not relevant.  Think of the annoyance it would be if you could not change a value because somewhere else in the program there was a `const` reference to it. How would this be tracked? The book-keeping required would be insane.

Comment: @molbdnilo Ah, I understand now. Thank you.

Comment: OT.: deleting `this->p` and then assigning a copy of `*rhs.p` while `&rhs == this` looks like a guarantee to shoot in your own foot for me. ;-) I sometimes saw a previous check for `this != &rhs` and this example illustrates very nicely why this makes very sense.

Comment: @user4581301 I think you are totally right. Thank you.

Comment: @Scheff, yes indeed, that's undefined behavior.

Comment: @Scheff Yes. I know this code is not good. This is referred to as a bad code in *Effective C++ 3rd Edition*.

Comment: Wait. Changing `delete p;` to `delete rhs.p;` still works. Why?

Comment: You can still `delete` a const pointer. You aren't changing the value of the pointer, you are ending the life of what it points to.

Comment: @matn because `delete p` doesn't change the `p` - and only `p` itself is const for const reference. And even if `p` was a const pointer, you'd still be able to call `delete` on it.

Comment: Its a bug in the Standard. The similar bug exists in the C Standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So I think `delete p;` may change the member `p` of `rhs` though `rhs` is a const reference.

1. No. `delete p;` doesn't change `p`. Invalidation is not modification.
2. Regardless, having a const reference to an object (`rhs`) does not by any means prevent the referred object form being modified. It merely prevents modification through the const reference. In this case we access the object through `this` which happens to be a pointer to non-const, so modification is allowed.

> Someone may insist that "to render a pointer invalid is not to change the value of a pointer" but I don't find such a statement in the standard.

The behaviour of delete expression is specified in [expr.delete]. Nowhere in that section does it mention that the operand is modified.

Becoming invalid is specified like this:

> [basic.compound]
>
> ... A pointer value becomes invalid when the storage it denotes reaches the end of its storage duration ...

Note that it is the **value** that becomes invalid. The pointer still has the same value because the pointer was not modified. The value that the pointer had and still has is simply a value that no longer points to an object - it is invalid.

---

> Supplement: I've changed `delete p;` to `delete rhs.p;`, but it still works. Why?

Answer 2. From previous question no longer applies, but answer 1. does. `delete rhs.p;` does not modify `rhs.p`.

Comment: For later reader: the statement "A pointer value becomes invalid when ..." can be found in N4713(C++20) and N4659(C++17) but not in N3092(C++11) or N4140(C++14).

Comment: _Note that it is the value that becomes invalid. The pointer still has the same value_ Wait. Does it become invalid or the pointer has the same value? It can't be both.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer it can be both, and is. The same value that used to be valid is now invalid. It is still the same value. I find it hard to express this unambiguously in English.

Comment: @eerorika in a discussion under some CWG issue Mike Miller told that the value of an object could be changed only by a store. Which means that freeing memory generates a store into each pointer pointing into the freed region. Storing invalid pointer value into it.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer how did you come to the conclusion that stores are generated into each pointer?

Comment: @eerorika if a value could be changed only by a store and pointer values become invalid when a region of memory is freed, then this invalidation is performed by a store

Comment: @LanguageLawyer but why do you think that the value changed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189985/discussion-between-language-lawyer-and-eerorika).

Answer (score 3):

Calling `delete` on a member pointer frees the memory the pointer *points to* but does *not* change the pointer itself. Thus, it does not change the bitwise contents of the object, thus it can be done in a `const` member.

C++ only cares about bitwise const (of the object the method is invoked on). Not logical const. If no bits in *the object* change, then all is well - const wise - as far as the C++ language is concerned. It does *not* matter whether the *logical* behaviour of the object is changed (for example by changing something member pointers point to). That's not what the compiler checks for.

Comment: Is the phrase "but does not change the pointer itself" guaranteed in the standard? As I cited in my question, the standard says *delete-expression* invalidates the related pointers. Why can we say "To invalidate a pointer never change the value of the pointer"?

Comment: @matn I have not checked the standatd text. But I would be *very* surprised if it said anything about the pointer itself changing. A pointer is just a variable holding an address of something else, and to change it would require work to be done, and in C++ you don't pay for what you don't use/ask for. So, silently paying the cost of changing the bits of the pointer when doing a `delete` would be *very* un-C++-like. As far as invalidation goes, that does not require the pointer to change. That just means it's no longer valid for you to dereference it.

Comment: Thank you. Your explanation sounds so natural. It seems I'm too paranoid.

Comment: _does not change the pointer itself_ Are you sure? https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.stc#4 says that the values of pointers become _invalid pointer values_. If a pointer value was _pointed to_ an object and then became _invalid pointer value_, how it didn't change?